# VBA - Check a range in sheet1 for a variable and create a list on sheet2 of each occurence of the variable

Tags: list, vba

What I want to do is check sheet1, column3 for a variable that I have defined as combobox1.value on sheet2.

I want the macro to list each time it finds the value of combobox1 in sheet1 on sheet2 along with 2 offset values.

I am completely lost and cannot find anything similar to this on Stack overflow.

```
      Sub make_list()
Dim grower As String
Dim r As Range
grower = Sheets("Grower Reporting").ComboBox1.Value

Set r = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Range("E:E").Find(grower, Range("e1"), _
LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
i = 1
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = r.Address
    Do
        'Add cell references to a list on sheet1 column E.
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Cells(r.Row, 3).Address
        'Add any additional offset values here
        i = i + 1
        Set r = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Range("e:e").FindNext(r)
    Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress
End If
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is check in column e on sheet "Grower Rejection Data" how many times "grower" variable appears and list each occurrence on sheet "Grower Reporting" starting in cell h31. I hope that helps make a bit clearer what I am attempting.

Comment: What have you tried? The functions you need to look at are `expression.Find` and `expression.FindNext` where expression represents a `Range` object.

Comment: I tried naming r as a range to check for instances of the variable in a specific column. I was able to get the function to identify the variable but I am stumped on how to generate of list of each occurrence and the values of their adjacent cells. I will try what you have posted above and see what I can come up with. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
Set R = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Range("E:E").Find(grower, Range("E1"), _      LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
i = 31
If Not R Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = R.Address
    Do
        Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 38).Value = R.Value
        Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 39).Value = R.Offset(0,1).Value
        Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 40).Value = R.Offset(0,2).Value           
        i = i + 1
        Set R = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Range("E:E").FindNext(R)
    Loop While Not R Is Nothing And R.Address <> firstAddress
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried to plug in my information in the above but I am getting a type mismatch error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. As you might have noticed, I'm not the strongest programmer.

Comment: I have edited my question above to provide more details. I appreciate all of the help so far.

Comment: When you set R the first time, make sure that your ranges match. for instance, your ranges should be `Range("E:E")` and `Range("E1")`.

Comment: Got it. That seemed to work. Please see the above edited code. Now I am getting a list on "Sheet1" not of the value of combobox1 but of the cells location i.e. "$c$73" and so on. What the ultimate aim of this is to generate a list with the grower name and the data to the right and left of it to create a quick summary.